# Double Ahah GET request when Firebug Enabled

Tags: ajax, firefox, get, firebug

Strange issue, when Firebug is enabled (and only then) does my Javascript start making double GET request (AHAH) at what appears to be random.

The result of this double call is that the code returned from the server (PHP generated Google Map / Javascript) is spat out on screen.

This issue does not occur in any other browsers unless firebug is enabled (which only leaves firefox).

Im really lost as to what might be causing this and how to solve it. Any input much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if there is an underlying bug that Firebug is making more apparent.  An example would be a race condition. Perhaps in normal running conditions one of the two requests blocks the other, but under a debugger there might be enough time for both requests to fire.

Kind of an odd idea, but I think I've seen something similar before.

Beside that, I can't venture any better suggestion without seeing code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, and found two issues that might be at work.

First, if you have any links with an empty source (src=''), try removing those and seeing if that fixes the issue.

Second, http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2010/1/8/A-Side-Effect-of-ySlow-and-Firebug explains that there are a few spots where Firebug makes additional calls. You can uncheck boxes to turn off this behavior (the blog post explains where).